# Cayley graph as a 1-skeleton

Tags: geometric-group-theory

A Cayley graph consists of vertices and edges, and distances are defined for elements of a given group. Then what about the edges? It is stated that "the 1-skeleton of a Cayley complex is a Cayley graph." Then, are the edges 1-cells attached between pairs of points that are of distance 1 so that distances for points *on the edges* can be defined? Moreover, is it for this reason that (topological) paths and loops, which are continuous functions defined on an interval $I \subset R$, can be defined regarding fundamental groups?

Comment: Your question is somewhat rambling and unclear. Are you asking how to define the Cayley graph and its metric?

Comment: Thank you. I am asking if the metric on a Cayley graph is also defined with regard to the edges.

Comment: The default assumption is that the restriction of the metric to each edge is isometric to $[0,1]$.